# How to fix this bug in a onEdit() function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automate the task of typing the date of records I make in a sheet. So, when I start typing in the first cell of the row, the script puts today date in the second cell (if it's empty). But it isn't working. Why?

```
function onEdit() {   
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "students_tasks" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 0) { 
      var dataCell0 = r.offset(0, 1);
      if(dataCell0.getValue() == '') {
        dataCell0.setValue("any info, e.g., today date");
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranges are 1-indexed, therefore, you should change your column comparison to the following:

```
if (r.getColumn() == 1) { 
    // ...
}
```